# I'm trying to use this function (which I found on a website) to link google form questions with a spread sheet but i keep getting error in line 4

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to  use this function (which I found on a website) to link google form questions with a spread sheet but I keep getting error in line 4
Error   Attempted to execute myFunction, but could not save.

```
    function getDataFromGoogleSheets () {
      const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1xYldb3csabrznjvapWPlIPAkEVQAyKlLQGzl810mG3Y');
      const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("clinic");
      const [header, ...data] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
      const choices = {};
      header.forEach(function(title, index) {
        choices[title] = data.map((row) => row[index]).filter((e) => e!=="");
      });
      return choices;  
    }

    function populateGoogleForms() {
      const GOOGLE_FORM_ID = '1jg4vooSWG4BY7z_9tMQV5aVaTOGeauC3ad3vsfvhGgk';
      const googleForm = FormApp.openById(GOOGLE_FORM_ID);
      const items = googleForm.getItems();
      const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets;//<======== Missing () in function call
      items.forEach(function(item){
        const itemTitle = item.getTitle();
        if(itemTitle in choices){
          const itemType = item.getType();
          switch (itemType) {
            case FormApp.ItemType.CHECKBOX:
              item.asCheckboxItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
              break;
            case FormApp.ItemType.LIST:
              item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
              break;
            case FormApp.ItemType.MULTIPLE_CHOICE:
              item.asMultipleChoiceItem().setChoiceValues(choices[itemTitle]);
              break;
            default:
              Logger.log('ignore question',itemTitle)
          }
        }
      });
      ss.toast('Google Form Updated !!');
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a table of data.  Note: I don't following links to spreadsheets

Answer (score 1):

This `const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets;` needs to be this `const choices = getDataFromGoogleSheets();`

It's a common error with using the new editor.   My guess is that the people that wrote the new editor don't ever use it.  If they did, they'd be a lot more inclined to change it.

Comment: thank you for answering, I added the missing () but still got the same error

Comment: Well I guess you have another problem to debug then